# App Engine Search API - Sort Results

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have several entities that I am searching across that include dates, and the Search API works great across all of them except for one thing - sorting.

Here's the data model for one of my entities (simplified of course):

```
class DepositReceipt(ndb.Expando):
    #Sets creation date
    creation_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

And the code to create the `search.Document` where `de` is an instance of the entity:

```
document = search.Document(doc_id=de.key.urlsafe(),
    fields=[search.TextField(name='deposit_key', value=de.key.urlsafe()),
            search.DateField(name='created', value=de.creation_date),
            search.TextField(name='settings', value=de.settings.urlsafe()),
            ])
```

This returns a valid document.

---

And finally the problem line. I took this snippet from the official GAE Search API tutorial and just changed the direction of the sort to `DESCENDING` and changed the search expression to `created` (the date property from the `Document` above).

```
expr_list = [search.SortExpression(
    expression="created", default_value='',
    direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING)]
```

---

I don't think this is important, but the rest of the search code looks like this:

```
sort_opts = search.SortOptions(expressions=expr_list)

query_options = search.QueryOptions(
    cursor=query_cursor,
    limit=_NUM_RESULTS,
    sort_options=sort_opts)  

query_obj = search.Query(query_string=query, options=query_options)

search_results = search.Index(name=index_name).search(query=query_obj)
```

---

In production, I get this error message:

```
InvalidRequest: Failed to parse search request "settings:ag5zfmdoaWRvbmF0aW9uc3IQCxIIU2V0dGluZ3MYmewDDA"; failed to parse date
```

Changing the `expression="created"` to anything else works perfectly fine.  This also happens across my other entity types that use dates, so I have no idea what's going on. Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `default_value` needs to be a valid date, rather than `''` as you have it.